# How to get data from server in android

Tags: android, server

Suppose i want to include several videos in an app that would be accessible only when connected to internet , what would be the steps required in order to use that :

steps like where to store those videos and how to access them in my app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-video-formats-in-android-using-videoview/28299

Shows how to play videos in android using videoView

Comment: i know what  View to use and how to access it from sdcard or internal memory , i am asking how to access it from server .

Comment: you can use videoView.setVideoURI(); to set url